# MySQL Query to discard records based on their status on a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE qr_code (
    id   int(10) primary key auto_increment,
    code int(10) not null
);

CREATE TABLE area_qrcode (
    id         int(10) primary key auto_increment,
    area_id    int(10) not null,
    qr_code_id int(10) not null,
    status     set('open', 'close')
);
```

In my tables, I have the following records:

```
-- qr_code
+----+------+
| id | code |
+----+------+
|  1 |  200 |
|  2 |  201 |
|  3 |  202 |
+----+------+

-- areaqr_code
+----+---------+------------+--------+
| id | area_id | qr_code_id | status |
+----+---------+------------+--------+
|  1 |       2 |          1 | open   |
|  2 |       4 |          3 | close  |
+----+---------+------------+--------+
```

I want to select from table `qr_code` all records that are not in status *open* in the `area_qrcode` table. `qr_code.id` corresponds to `area_qrcode.qr_code_id`.

A good result set would be:

```
+----+------+
| id | code |
+----+------+
|  2 |  201 |
|  3 |  202 |
+----+------+
```

I'm using the following query, but it's not working as I expect because if the table `area_qrcode` has no values corresponding to the values in `qr_code`, then I get no results for those records:

```
SELECT
    qr.*
FROM
    `qr_code` as qr,
    `area_qrcode` as aq 
WHERE
    (
        aq.qr_code_id = qr.id and
        aq.status != 'open'
    )
    OR
    (
        aq.qr_code_id != qr.id
    );
```

**What can I change to get records from `qr_code` even if there are not related records in `areaqr_code`?**

Answer (score 1):

You can get your result with a subselect:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `qr_code` as qr
where 
    qr.id NOT IN (
        SELECT qr_code_id 
        FROM area_qrcode 
        WHERE status = 'open'
    );
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/775a0/1)

With a LEFT JOIN you can get your result too:

```
SELECT 
    qr.* 
FROM 
    qr_code as qr 
LEFT JOIN 
    area_qrcode as aq 
ON
    qr.id = aq.qr_code_id
AND
    aq.status = 'open'
WHERE
    aq.qr_code_id IS NULL;
```

[Updated Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/775a0/10)

A third possibility (not so intuitive as the first one):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    `qr_code` as qr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        area_qrcode
    WHERE
        status = 'open'
    AND
        qr_code_id = qr.id
);
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/775a0/12)

Comment: Minor typo,remove the comma

Answer (score 0):

SELECT qr.* FROM `qr_code` as qr LEFT JOIN `area_qrcode` as aq ON aq.qr_code_id=qr.id and aq.status!='open' OR(aq.qr_code_id!=qr.id)

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper join, that will prevent confusion.

```
SELECT qr_code.id,qr_code.code 
FROM qr_code 
LEFT JOIN area_qrcode 
ON area_qrcode.qr_code_id = qr_code.id
WHERE area_qrcode.status <> 'open' OR area_qrcode.status IS NULL
```

[**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcbc1/2)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this is the query that you're looking for:

```sql
SELECT q.id, q.code
FROM qr_code q
LEFT JOIN area_qrcode aq
ON aq.qr_code_id = q.id
WHERE (aq.status IS NULL OR aq.status <> 'open')
```

Will result in:

```
ID  CODE
--  ----
2   201
3   202
```

Fiddle available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce226/4).